# How to do an Hlookup based on another Hlookup?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup

I have a Monthly Reporting Package I have to update every month and the rollover process is rather tedious so I'm trying to automate some of it.

I have to update plan and prior year numbers on my P&L and to update my prior year numbers I look at our prior year P&L by month.

The problem is that it is broken out by entity under each month. So I have entered the month number for each month in row 6 and the entity name is in row 8.

I need to be able to lookup the month and then lookup the entity under that month and return row 10, 11, etc. please see below picture for reference. I believe an index match is going to be the answer but I can't get it to work. I'm using September as a reference. So I essentially need to combine the following formulas.

`=HLOOKUP(9,'PL - Consolidating YTD 2017'!$6:$49,5,FALSE)`

`=HLOOKUP("Janus International Group, LLC",'PL - Consolidating YTD 2017'!$8:$49,3,FALSE)`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try shifting the range with an offset match:

`=HLOOKUP("Janus International Group, LLC",OFFSET($B8:$Q49,0,MATCH(9,'PL - Consolidating YTD 2017'!$6:$6,0)-2),3,FALSE)`

**Pseudo code to try and make it easier to see what's happening:**

`=HLOOKUP([CompanyName],OFFSET([First Monthly Lookup Range],0,MATCH([Month],[Month Row],0)-2),3,FALSE)`

**Other Considerations:**

For `MATCH([Month],[Month Row],0)-2` you might need to change this offset, i.e. the `-2` depending on how many columns you have between Column A and where the first month in your data starts, I have assumed the firs month starts in Column B and that all months have a maximum of 16 columns. You can widen out this range though without ill effects, for example you could make it `$B8:$AA49`; it doesn't really matter how wide it is, as long as its at least as wide as the month with the most columns.

Comment: Thanks man, that worked like a charm, I really appreciate your help!